# Show data from API on Django template

Tags: python, django, rest, api, django-templates

I'm trying to show the fetched data on an API to the Django template.

Here's what I've tried on
`home.html`

```
<h1>Title: {{data.title}}</h1>
```

Here's my `views.py` which gets the data from `services.py`

```
class IndexData(TemplateView):
    def get(self, request):
        article_data = services.get_data()
        return render(request, 'pages/home.html', article_data)
```

Here's the `services.py`

```
def get_data(title, url, description, body, datePublished):
  url = 'https://contextualwebsearch-websearch-v1.p.rapidapi.com/api/Search/WebSearchAPI'
    params = {"autoCorrect": "true", "pageNumber": "1", "pageSize": "10", "q": "police", "safeSearch": "true" }
    headers = {...}
    r = requests.get(url, headers=headers, params=params)
    data = r.json()
    article_data = {'data': data['value']}
    return article_data
```

The returned `json` is

```
{   "_type":"all",
    "didUMean":"",
    "totalCount":2923,
    "relatedSearch":[
       "coronavirus",
       "new york",
       "post",
       "getty",
       "times",
       "china",
       "council",
       "shares",
       "americans",
       "pandemics",
       "prime",
       "19 crisis"

 ],
    "value":[      
      {         
          "title":"COVID-19 And The Failure Of Populism",
          "url":"https://www.forbes.com/sites/riskmap/2020/04/02/covid-19-and-the-failure-of-populism/",
          "description":"Populist presidents, reliant on their need to constantly convey positive messaging that bolsters their support, have struggled to take the decisive, forward-looking action that the coronavirus crisis demands.",
          "body":").\nHow will the pandemic play out in these countries?\nSteering countries through the pandemic and an eventual recovery will then be the responsibility of leaders who will have lost credibility, as well as the veneer of their all is well message. The narrative that allowed people in certain countries to latch on to something they approved of in their leader (the economy is doing well, the corruption of previous regimes was intolerable, there was no alternative, etc) while disregarding all the caveats of things they disliked, may now give way to harsher judgement. Hopefully, if there is any silver lining, the public might start trusting experts and reliable sources of information again, and will begin to question their leaders more actively.\nEither way, populist leaders like Trump, AMLO, and Bolsonaro will each have demonstrated a great inability to manage any criticism, no matter who it comes from or how constructive it might be. On the contrary, they seem to double-down",
     "keywords":"",
     "language":"en",
     "isSafe":true,
     "datePublished":"2020-04-02T11:00:00",
     "provider":{
        "name":"forbes"

 },
          "image":{
             "url":"https://thumbor.forbes.com/thumbor/fit-in/1200x0/filters%3Aformat%28jpg%29/https%3A%2F%2Fspecials-images.forbesimg.com%2Fdam%2Fimageserve%2F99b82bcbe089442095046d2dbb9ecbf9%2F0x0.jpg%3Ffit%3Dscale",
            "height":800,
        "width":1200,
        "thumbnail":"https://rapidapi.contextualwebsearch.com/api/thumbnail/get?value=37416569554313599",
        "thumbnailHeight":200,
        "thumbnailWidth":300,
        "base64Encoding":null,
        "name":null,
        "title":null,
        "imageWebSearchUrl":null

}

}
```

What did I miss?

Answer (score 2):

Just do in your template

```html
{{ article_data.value.0.title }}
```

Answer (score 0):

`value` key in the response is a list. You need to access it's first element too.

Probably this should work, in `service.py` you can change the line where you're declaring `article_data` to this:

```
article_data = {'data': data['value'][0]}
```

Answering the follow-on question from comment, for `datePublished` since it's the same level as `title` you can just use `data.datePublished` in your template.

Comment: Okay i'll try what you suggested. If I would also want to get the `datePublished`, would I access it with ```article_data = {'data': data['datePublished']``` or is there a better way?

Comment: you can just use `data.datePublished` it has already got that data.

Comment: weird. it returned `list index out of range`